# Update Query with PDO sum

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've one input field of Quantity Parameter and want to add the value in current Input field and here's my code which is not working.

```
$quantity_add = htmlspecialchars($_POST['quantity_add']);

$sql1 = "UPDATE items set quantity=quantity+? where id=?";
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt1->execute(array($quantity_add,$id));

$success = "Added";
```

Please help me to fix the above code.

Comment: Where is `$id` coming from?

Comment: $id is coming from a table and i'm  using a bootstrap modal popup so passing that $id value via this code  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

Comment: Actually the query is now working but it updates all row fields of quantity, i think $id is missing